# Show one solution of ODE system is bounded above and below

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Defined on $\mathbb{R}$, there're three $C^1$ functions $u_{1}(x),u_{2}(x),u_{3}(x)$. Given the ODE system
\begin{cases}
u_{1}'(x)&=u_{2}(x)u_{3}(x) \\
u_{2}'(x)&=-u_{1}(x)u_{3}(x) \\
u_{3}'(x)&=-k^2u_{1}(x)u_{2}(x) \\
\end{cases}
Here $0<k<1$. The initial condition is $u_{1}(0)=0,u_{2}(0)=u_{3}(0)=1$.
Show that $\sqrt{1-k^2}\leq u_{3}(x)\leq1$.

I have known $u_{1}^2(x)+u_{2}^2(x)=1$ by combining the first two equations. However, I haven't found how to continue the boundeness of $u_{3}$.

By differentiating $u_{3}$ I got $u_{3}''=k^2(u_{1}^2-u_{2}^2)u_{3}$ but it seems no use. By $u_{1}^2+u_{2}^2=1$ we may know $1\geq 2u_{1}u_{2}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similarly to $u_1^2+u_2^2=1$ you can also combine the first and third equation to get
$$
0=k^2u_1'u_1+u_3'u_3=\tfrac{1}{2}(k^2u_1^2+u_3^2)'\\
\Rightarrow k^2u_1^2+u_3^2=1\\
\Rightarrow \begin{cases}u_3^2\leq1\\u_3^2=1-k^2u_1^2\geq1-k^2\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Hi Max, I reviewed this question today, only combining the first and third equation cannot get $u_{3}^{2}\geq 1-k^2$. So it needs another step, combining the second third equation.

Comment: You are right, I used your previously achieved result $u_1^2+u_2^2=1\Rightarrow u_1^2\leq1$ in the step $1-k^2u_1^2\geq1-k^2$.